# ssh permission denied when prefixing with ssh protocol

Tags: ssh, command-line

I try to add a ssh key to my GitLab account in order to use it through npm.

I added my key following https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/.

```
ssh -T git@gitlab.com
```

Is working fine and deliver the message *Welcome to Gitlab, username*.

But `ssh -T ssh://git@gitlab.com` is not working and give me this error message:

> Permission denied (publickey).

And when I run `npm install` on my node project where I added my node module as a dependency inside the `package.json` file, it's returning the following error:

```
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@gitlab.com/myproject/myproject.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Permission denied (publickey).
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
```

I added my dependency inside `package.json` as follow:

```
"my-project": "git@gitlab.com:myproject/myproject.git",
```

I'm not comfortable with ssh and key pairing, if anyone could tell me what is wrong with my configuration it will help me a lot, thanks.

Comment: Can you paste ssh -vvvvT git@gitlab.com and ssh -vvvvT ssh://git@gitlab.com somewhere?

Comment: Still having issues?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's kind of funny to be misled by the following line (talking about myself):

```
ssh -T ssh://git@gitlab.com
```

The command doesn't expect actually a protocol prefix, but a **hostname** prefixed or not by a **user name** followed by an **arobase**, as said the manual page:

> **ssh** [-1246AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec] [-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11]
>                [-i identity_file] [-J [user@]host[:port]] [-L address] [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port] [-Q query_option] [-R address]
>                [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port] [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]] **[user@]hostname [command]**

Here, it takes actually **`ssh://git`** as a **user name**. That's why it won't log in since the user name which whom you connect has to be **`git`**, and not `ssh://git`.

Answer (score 0):

## What's the difference between "**SSH**", "**ssh**" & "**ssh://**"?

**SSH** is a transport layer protocol. [link](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253)

**ssh** is an `OpenSSH SSH` client. `OpenSSH` is the connectivity tool for remote login with the `SSH` protocol. [link](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh.1)

**ssh://** is a Uniform Resource Locator (URL). [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL)

---

`ssh -T git@gitlab.com` - Using an ssh client, log in to gitlab.com with username as git

`ssh -T ssh://git@gitlab.com` - Using an ssh client, log in to gitlab.com with username as ssh://git (Thanks [Amessihel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4375327/amessihel) for the detailed answer)

`ssh://git@gitlab.com/myproject/myproject.git` - Instructs the application accessing this URL that it requires ssh client to access, and if there an ssh client installed on the operating system, opens the SSH client, log in to gitlab.com with username git and access the `myproject/myproject.git` repo. Chrome understand this URL, copy this URL on the chrome address bar and hit enter.

Just like any URL, for example, https://google.com. Many clients support HTTP, like wget, curl or a web browser, and for HTTP & HTTPS URL operating systems will open web browsers.